# Getting results without using IN

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Oracle has a limit on the arguments in the `IN` statement of 1000, I believe, is there a way around this? If I had a statement similar to this (with 1000 ids or more):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "VERSION" 
WHERE "VERSION"."VERSION_ID" IN 
      (59156, 57045, 54779, 54048, 54048, 
       --- long list ---
       12648, 11160, 11160, 11160, 11160)
```

How could I write simple count statement?

Comment: Where are these `version_id` values coming from?  99 times out of 100, they're coming from somewhere else in the database in which case you just need to take the `select` statement that returns the values and put that in the `in` clause.  If the values are coming from somewhere else, you'd often want to load them into a collection or temporary table and use that in your `in` clause.  Other than that, you can have multiple `in` clauses or get even more esoteric but that rarely produces code that people are happy to maintain...

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause

Comment: @a1ex07 can you make one of those examples into an answer so I can accept that one. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a temporary table to hold all of the IDs you want to search on then join in that temporary table.

```
create table tmpIds(id int not null)
insert into tmpIds (59156)
insert into tmpIds (57045)
etc...

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM "VERSION"
INNER JOIN tmpIds ON 
"VERSION"."VERSION_ID" = tmpIds.id

drop table tmpIds
```

Comment: Executing DDL causes implicit commit which can mess the transaction management. A better approach is to use [global temporary table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11633) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also OR IN clauses. Such as:

```sql
select count(*)
from version
where version_id in (1,2,3,4,5,...255)
or version_id in(256,257,258,....);
```